# Infinite loop during printing the Binary tree

Tags: c, binary-tree

Here is my code, which is working almost correct except infinite loop in `printInTree()`

```
struct node{
    char text[100];
    int count;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* addNode(struct node* n,char w[]){
    int cond=0;
    if(n == NULL){
        n=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->count=1;
        n->left=NULL;
        n->right=NULL;
        strcpy(n->text,w);
    }
    else if((cond=strcmp(w,n->text))==0){
        n->count++;
    }
    else if(cond>0){
        n->right=addNode(n->right,w);
    }
    else{
        n->left=addNode(n->left,w);
    }
    return n;
};

void printInTree(struct node* p){   
    while(p != NULL){                //infinite loop here.
        printInTree(p->left);
        printf("%3s - %d\n",p->text,p->count);
        printInTree(p->right);

    }
}

void b_treeDemo(){
    struct node *root=NULL;
    FILE* f=fopen("main.c","r");
    char word[100];
    while(1){
        if(getWord(f,word)>0){
            if(isalpha(word[0])){
                root=addNode(root,word);
            }
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    printInTree(root);
}
```

How to break this loop so that it prints the tree in inorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to recursively print a tree, so this is what you want:

```
void printInTree(struct node* p){   
    if (p == NULL) return;
    printInTree(p->left);
    printf("%3s - %d\n",p->text,p->count);
    printInTree(p->right);
}
```

The recursive call will stop when you meet a NULL child. You don't need a `while` here.

Comment: This is the canonical way for printing a tree in order. If this didn't work, the problem must somewhere else.

Comment: There is no loop in the solution: you proceed by recursion, not iteration (loop).

Comment: It might be in the data structure itself, but for what I can tell by comment under my answer it should've worked.

Comment: Actually i used this if as base case earlier(without removing the loop). That's why i judged the book by cover only :P

Comment: Aha, so @StefanoSanfilippo's guess (under my answer) was close, but not precise ;)

Comment: But hey, I was first and you stole a checkmark from me! ;) (just kidding, you can keep it).

Answer (score 5):

`p` doesn't change in the loop, what would make it finite? What you wanted to do is probably

```
if(!p) return;
```

instead of the `while` loop. (To understand recursion first you need to understand recursion).

Comment: Note, that this is exactly what Stefano suggested and you said it didn't work ;)

Comment: +1. I guess the OP kept the `while` loop and only changed the condition, instead of replacing with an `if`.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be combining recursion and iteration. In your `printInTree` function, you use recursion to invoke the same function on the child nodes, however, you also have this inside of a `while` loop, making sure `p != NULL`. For any given invocation of the function `printInTree`, unless `p == NULL`, that invocation will be infinite.

If you change the `while` to `if`, your code should run without infinite looping.

Answer (score 0):

p does not change by the end of the while loop (which as others have pointed out should be an if statement)